# How i can export an Image per Row with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have this DataFrame with percentages, and I´m plotting using

```
__  1   2   3   4
1   0.376344    0.215054    0.408602    0.000000
2   0.838710    0.000000    0.000000    0.150538
3   0.258065    0.096774    0.021505    0.623656
4   0.064516    0.397849    0.516129    0.010753
5   0.075269    0.064516    0.043011    0.817204

table.plot(kind='barh', stacked=True, figsize=(100, 100))
```

I´m getting a graph with all the rows being plotted, the thing is that i need to export a single .png  per each row of the dataframe, the example is only 5 rows, but the real dataframe is about a thousand rows so i need to export about a thousand `.png`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try plotting each row and do stuff with `iterrows` method of `pandas.DataFrame`, see the documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html).

```
for _, row in table.iterrows():
    # do plotting stuff here with row 
    # (row is a dict columns as keys and rows as values so to say.)
    # export it as png
```